# Number of license plates with at least 2 numbers

Tags: combinatorics

If a license plate has $7$ characters from $A-Z$ and $0-9$, how many plates will have at least $2$ numbers?

I was thinking about finding the total amount of license plates and subtracting those that have less than $2$ numbers

total license plates -> $36^7$

$0$ numbers -> $10^7$

$1$ number -> $~7 \cdot ~^{10}P_3$

Would the final answer be answer $~36^7 - 10^7 - ~7 \cdot ~^{10}P_3$? Or is there a different approach to this?

Comment: plates with no numbers - it should be $26^7$. Plates with exactly one number should be ${10 \choose 1} {7 \choose 1} 26^6$

Comment: @MathLover Please turn your comment into an answer so that the question can be closed.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sure, I just did. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the total number of license plates from $26$ alphabets and $10$ digits is $36^7$. Though your idea is right, rest of the work is not.

Number of license plates with no digits in it:  $~26^7$

Number of license plates with *exactly* one digit: $10 \cdot 7 \cdot 26^6~$,
as there are $10$ ways to choose a digit and $7$ ways to choose a place for that digit in $7$ character license plate. Rest $6$ places have choice of $26$ alphabets each.

So the answer should be $~36^7 - 26^7 - 70 \cdot 26^6$